# OperationError on first query to django sqlite3 database

Tags: python, django, sqlite

The beginning of my `settings.py` has the following.

```
import os, sys

PROJECT_PATH            = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
CURRENT_DIR             = os.path.dirname(__file__)
TEMPLATE_DIRS           = (os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, 'templates'),)
STATICFILES_DIRS        = (os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, 'static'),)

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
  # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 
    'NAME': '/home/ubuntu/myapp/myapp',       
  }
}
```

I get the following in my error log after a call from `views.py` to the database.

```
[time] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 372, in count
[time] [error]     return self.query.get_count(using=self.db)
[time] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 423, in get_count
[time] [error]     number = obj.get_aggregation(using=using)[None]
[time] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 389, in get_aggregation
[time] [error]     result = query.get_compiler(using).execute_sql(SINGLE)
[time] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 839, in execute_sql
[time] [error]     cursor = self.connection.cursor()
[time] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 324, in cursor
[time] [error]     cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
[time] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 306, in _cursor
[time] [error]     self._sqlite_create_connection()
[time] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 296, in _sqlite_create_connection
[time] [error]     self.connection = Database.connect(**kwargs)
[time] [error] OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

How do I go about correctly referring to my database file in `settings.py`?

Comment: are you running this with uwsgi/guinicorn? does that process have permission to access the database file?

Comment: there is a `wsgi.py` file

Comment: are you using apache/wsgi or a separate wsgi server like uwsgi or gunicorn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run `python manage.py syncdb`, as that process will create the database before you can access it in `views.py` or anywhere else.

Comment: I ran `python manage.py syncdb` and I get `(use ./manage.py migrate to migrate these)`

Comment: Because you are running south.

Comment: I deleted the database file `myapp` and ran `python manage.py syncdb` again and did not get the above error but I still get the `OperationalError` at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

`'NAME': '/home/ubuntu/myapp/myapp'` looks to me like you're referring to a folder instead of a file. For SQLite, the database name must be a full path, including the name of a file, so, as you already got your project's folder programmatically, you could use that to construct the file path:

`'NAME': os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'mydb.db')`

Comment: In Linux systems, files don't need extensions.

Comment: true, but it still looks to me as if he specified myapp the name of his virtualenv, and the next myapp is the actual project folder...although im just guessing here, could be wrong yes...

Comment: When I run `file myapp` in the root of my django repository I get `myapp SQLite 3.x database`

Comment: I tried `'NAME': os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'mydb.db')` and get the same error